# How to encode the hex string representation of an account id in Substrate using Rust?

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

Given a hex representation: `0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d`, we can get the AccountId it represents using `keyring.encodeAddress()` using JavaScript. However, what is the corresponding function in Rust?

AccountId is the address of the [Substrate](https://substrate.dev/) user's address. For eg, `5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY` is the account id of Alice, from the Substrate's dev chain.

Comment: Anyway look at [hex](https://crates.io/crates/hex)

Comment: @Stargateur I used the keywords known in the Substrate world and hence didn't feel the need to elaborate on it. Anyways, I have added the relevant hyperlink. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Stargateur you suggestion of `hex` won't work, getting the error of "Odd length". This hex value is scale coded. I need to decode it in that manner. Can you help me with that?

Also, if the question is clear now, can you remove the downvote so that it can reach more audience?

Comment: The hex address does not have any special encoding that would stop it from turning into bytes. Odd length error may be related to keeping `0x` at the front, or forgetting to copy all the characters in the string.

Comment: "I used the keywords known in the Substrate world and hence didn't feel the need to elaborate on it." not every one know substrate in fact I expect very few people know it, whereas the number of people knowing rust is much higher. You will increase the quality and the chance of getting a good answer if you describe what you want/need explicitly, then people who only know rust could make a good answer. Because for example, I will not read all the substate doc just to answer you. Your question is still unclean cause we still don't know how your hex value work. your example come from nowhere

Comment: @Stargateur yes, you are right. Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within rust, you should not really start with the hex representation, you want to work with bytes.

But assuming you have hex, you can convert a hex string to AccountId bytes using the `hex_literal::hex` macro:

```
let account: AccountId32 = hex_literal::hex!["d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"].into(),
```

> Note that `0x` is omitted from the hex literal.

Now you should have `[u8; 32]` wrapped in the `AccountId32` identity struct.

From there, you can simply do the same logic as done in the implementation for `Display` for `AccountId32`:

```
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
impl std::fmt::Display for AccountId32 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_ss58check())
    }
}
```

Basically the Address is the `ss58` encoded version of the Account Id bytes.

The ss58 codec library can be found here: https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/sp_core/crypto/trait.Ss58Codec.html

Comment: Can't I use the Display directly as `account` is `AccountId32` type for which `Display` is already implemented?

Comment: Yes, you could directly do `println!("{}", account)` I think

Comment: `let account: AccountId32 = hex_literal::hex!["d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"].into();
let ss58_account = account.to_ss58check();`

I got an error:`method not found in AccountId32`
I go to the definition, only find `#[cfg(feature = "std")]
impl Ss58Codec for AccountId32 {}`.
Does `Ss58Codec` only work under `std`?