# How to hardcode an address in the substrate runtime?

Tags: substrate

You can pre-set integer, string, and a lot of things manually within a pallet but how do I set an AccountId manually in pallet other than ensure_root functionality?

I would assume that since blockchain is already running for a long time, I am unable to change the chain spec genesis.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by pre-setting?

Comment: @kianenigma for example every dispatch call would transfer 1 Unit of DOT to the AccountId. I cannot find on how to set the said account in the code.

Comment: Would be helpful if you share some code that shows a dispatchable and clearly express what you want to achieve. I think I know what you want and the answer is probably simple, but the question is till pretty vague :)

Comment: hi @kianenigma,

The idea is like this 
`let donation: AccountId = '5axsca';

fn give_money(origin, amount: Balance) {
    Balance.transfer(origin, donation, amount)
}`

Based on the charity example, it actually created another account upon pallet instantiate but I do not want this way. Is this doable?

Comment: posted an answer, I hope it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, I can only assume that your question's correct title is: "***how to hardcode an address in the substrate runtime***".

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983883/how-to-encode-the-hex-string-representation-of-an-account-id-in-substrate-using). To briefly recap here, the AccountId type that is known inside the pallets is only bounded to these traits: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L195

So it is a bit harder to hardcode one ***inside*** a pallet, albeit still possible. A more sensible way would be to ***inject*** the hardcoded account into your pallet from outside as a configuration.

First, your config trait need to accept a type that contains this account:

```rust
trait Config: frame_system::Config {
   // A type that can deliver a single account id value to the pallet.
   type CharityDest: Get<<Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>
}
```

Then, to use it, you'd simple do:

```rust
// inside the `impl<T> Module<T>` or `impl<C> Pallet<T>` or `decl_module` where `T` is in scope.
some_transfer_function(T::CharityDest::get(), amount);
```

Finally, in your top level runtime file you can hardcode the AccountId and pass it in through, as such:

```rust
parameter_types! {
     pub CharityDest: AccountId = hex_literal::hex!["hex-bytes-of-account"].into()
}

impl my_pallet::Config for Runtime {
   type CharityDest = CharityDest;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the fact that the `AccountId` type of most runtimes is [`AccountId32`](https://docs.rs/sp-core/2.0.1/sp_core/crypto/struct.AccountId32.html), which implements [`Ss58Codec`](https://docs.rs/sp-core/2.0.1/sp_core/crypto/trait.Ss58Codec.html), meaning that it has a bunch of useful functions to convert from the Ss58 string to the account, so you can do something like

```rust
parameter_types! {
     pub CharityDest: AccountId = AccountId::from_ss58check("AccountSs58Format").unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate this. For the `AccountId::from_ss58check("AccountSs58Format")` , it can be in Polkadot, Kusama, or Substrate format right?

I also change the title of the question to reflect the question better.

Comment: Yes, and you can use this function to set which one you intend to use: https://docs.rs/sp-core/2.0.1/sp_core/crypto/fn.set_default_ss58_version.html.

Comment: When I want to use `from_ss58check` in my node-template, I import the trait:    `use sp_core::crypto::{KeyTypeId, Ss58Codec}`.  It reports error: `no Ss58Codec in crypto`. why?

Comment: This answer is no longer working.